# Prisma: Column Too Long

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

This is my entity:

```
model Post {
  ....
  content        String?
  ....
}
```

This `content` should contain `html` string which is long. How can I achieve this?

I am using `MSSQL`. Is there a type `varchar(max)` or something?

Comment: try `content String? @db.Text`.
I'm not sure it's work on MSSQL but give it a try

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is:

```
content        String? @db.VarChar(MAX)
```

It is applicable for `MSSQL` I have not tried for other DB.